# Use HTTPD's mod_rewrite and AngularJS RouteProvider with Parameters

Tags: angularjs, apache, mod-rewrite

I am trying to use HTTPD's mod_rewrite and AngularJS's routeProvider to allow users to access a webpage with a clean URL that will change its content based on some parameters in the URL.

For example, let's say there are profile pages for JohnSmith and JaneDoe. I want them to be able to access their pages via URL, like so:

```
http://my.example.com/JohnSmith
```

I want the AngularJS code to be able to grab the name "JohnSmith" from the URL, and use that for the REST call thusly:

```
$http.get('http://my.example.com/profile/name/' + $routeParams.profile)
```

So far, I have managed to get AngularJS to grab the correct profile IF the URL is formatted like one of the following:

```
http://my.example.com/#/JohnSmith
http://my.example.com/index.html#/JohnSmith
```

Here is the relevant code thus far:

index.html:

```
    <html ng-app="profile">
    <head>
        <title>Profile</title>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.14/angular.min.js">
        </script>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular-route.js"></script>
        <link rel='stylesheet' href='style/style-main.css' type='text/css' />
        <script src="js/app.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <ng-view></ng-view>
    </body>
</html>
```

app.js:

```
(function() {
var app = angular.module('profile', ['ngRoute']);

app.config(function($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider.when("/:profile",
    {
        templateUrl: "profile.html",
        controller:"ProfileController",
        controllerAs: "profile"
    });

});

app.controller("ProfileController", [ '$http', '$routeParams', function($http, $routeParams) {
    var SELF = this;
    SELF.profile = $routeParams.profile;
    console.log(SELF.profile);
}) ();
```

Using a clean URL like this:

```
http://my.example.com/JohnSmith
```

...will return a 404.

So I'm trying to use Apache's mod_rewrite to change the URL into a form that AngularJS can understand and extract the 'JohnSmith' parameter from.

I've got the following RewriteRule in place on my Apache node:

```
RewriteRule "(^[^\/#\.]+$)" "#/$1"
```

I've checked it out, and I know that this RewriteRule should trigger on any URL that doesn't contain any extra slashes, pound signs, or periods. Therefore, it should rewrite a URL like this:

```
http://my.example.com/JohnSmith
```

to this:

```
http://my.example.com/#/JohnSmith
```

That's a form that I know AngularJS can serve content for correctly, so after Apache rewrites the URL into that form, it should work, right?

Well, with that RewriteRule in place, trying to access the clean URL no longer results in a 404. In fact, if I right-click and select 'View Source', I can see that my browser has definitely attempted to load the HTML page. It looks like the routeProvider is no longer picking up the parameter from the URL, however.

How can I resolve this issue so the HTTPD RewriteRule and AngularJS routeProvider work together to provide the correct content using the clean URL?

Comment: You need to clean the url with help of angular not by .htaccess. You can check the following link to remove the hashtag
https://scotch.io/tutorials/pretty-urls-in-angularjs-removing-the-hashtag

Comment: I tried using that exact page long before posting this question. My code looked like this at that point:

Comment: app.js:  
`app.config(function($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {  
        $routeProvider.when("/:profile",  
        {  
            ...  
        });  
          
        $locationProvider.html5mode(true);  
    });`  
  
index.html:  
`<html ng-app="profile">  
    <head>  
        ...  
        <base href="/">  
    </head>  
...  
</html>`  
  
`http://my.example.com/JohnSmith`   
  
...returns a 404 error: "The requested URL /JohnSmith was not found on this server."